# Can there be a performance impact when running a load test on one azure website when you have multiple sites running

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We are running several azure websites (or web apps) on a medium instance. I would like to know if there will be an impact on performance on any of the other sites when running a simple load test on one of them. In other words, do these sites share the same processor/memory or is this handled differently in azure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the apps are in the same app service plan then yes there will be an impact.  Apps within the same app service plan share resources and capacity.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview/

Comment: For some reason I couldn't find that info. Thanks for the quick response.